# using Terminal on OSX Sierra and getting a random error after a command completes

Tags: go, terminal, homebrew

This random error shows up, looks like it's related to go, but I don't even have that version of go installed and the file being referenced does not exist.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling go through homebrew but nothing seems to change.  It happens randomly and shows up after I've executed a command (maybe 1/50 times).

```
failed MSpanList_Insert 0x2d6000 0x1e03e6f2951c 0x0
fatal error: MSpanList_Insert

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x279a4b)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:491 +0xad fp=0x7fff5fbff690 sp=0x7fff5fbff660
runtime.MSpanList_Insert(0x298e28, 0x2d6000)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.c:692 +0x8f fp=0x7fff5fbff6b8 sp=0x7fff5fbff690
MHeap_FreeSpanLocked(0x295a20, 0x2d6000, 0x100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.c:583 +0x163 fp=0x7fff5fbff6f8 sp=0x7fff5fbff6b8
MHeap_Grow(0x295a20, 0x8, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.c:420 +0x1a8 fp=0x7fff5fbff738 sp=0x7fff5fbff6f8
MHeap_AllocSpanLocked(0x295a20, 0x1, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.c:298 +0x365 fp=0x7fff5fbff778 sp=0x7fff5fbff738
mheap_alloc(0x295a20, 0x1, 0x12, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.c:190 +0x121 fp=0x7fff5fbff7a0 sp=0x7fff5fbff778
runtime.MHeap_Alloc(0x295a20, 0x1, 0x10000000012, 0x1f2e9)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.c:240 +0x66 fp=0x7fff5fbff7d8 sp=0x7fff5fbff7a0
MCentral_Grow(0x29d798, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/mcentral.c:197 +0x8b fp=0x7fff5fbff840 sp=0x7fff5fbff7d8
runtime.MCentral_CacheSpan(0x29d798, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/mcentral.c:85 +0x167 fp=0x7fff5fbff878 sp=0x7fff5fbff840
runtime.MCache_Refill(0x2d2000, 0x12, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/mcache.c:90 +0xa0 fp=0x7fff5fbff8a0 sp=0x7fff5fbff878
runtime.mcacheRefill_m()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/malloc.c:368 +0x57 fp=0x7fff5fbff8c0 sp=0x7fff5fbff8a0
runtime.onM(0x1f3ff8)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:273 +0x9a fp=0x7fff5fbff8c8 sp=0x7fff5fbff8c0
runtime.mallocgc(0x120, 0x198de0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/malloc.go:178 +0x849 fp=0x7fff5fbff978 sp=0x7fff5fbff8c8
runtime.newobject(0x198de0, 0x2d2000)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/malloc.go:353 +0x49 fp=0x7fff5fbff9a0 sp=0x7fff5fbff978
runtime.newG(0x3645a)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:233 +0x2a fp=0x7fff5fbff9b8 sp=0x7fff5fbff9a0
allocg(0x288380)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/proc.c:925 +0x1f fp=0x7fff5fbff9c8 sp=0x7fff5fbff9b8
runtime.malg(0x8000, 0x288420)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/proc.c:2106 +0x1f fp=0x7fff5fbff9f8 sp=0x7fff5fbff9c8
runtime.mpreinit(0x2887e0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/os_darwin.c:137 +0x27 fp=0x7fff5fbffa10 sp=0x7fff5fbff9f8
mcommoninit(0x2887e0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/proc.c:201 +0xc9 fp=0x7fff5fbffa38 sp=0x7fff5fbffa10
runtime.schedinit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/proc.c:138 +0x55 fp=0x7fff5fbffa60 sp=0x7fff5fbffa38
runtime.rt0_go(0x7fff5fbffa90, 0x3, 0x7fff5fbffa90, 0x0, 0x3, 0x7fff5fbffbd0, 0x7fff5fbffbd7, 0x7fff5fbffbdc, 0x0, 0x7fff5fbffbe1, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:95 +0x116 fp=0x7fff5fbffa68 sp=0x7fff5fbffa60
```

Comment: Have you tried install it manually without using Brew?

Comment: what does `echo $GOROOT` tell you?

Comment: What "command" completes? What is the Go version you have, and what is the go env output?

Comment: @RickyA echo $GOROOT returns blank

Comment: @JimB it happens randomly when I'm using terminal, the last few commands were 'git ...', 'ls', 'cd ...' ... etc.  
I have go1.8 darwin/amd64

Comment: @ithinkiknowruby: If you're not building something with Go, then the currently installed version is irrelevant. You have an old Go binary in your path somewhere that you are either executing directly, or indirectly through another command or even via the shell's autocompletion. Try to figure out which command triggers it. To narrow it down, the binary is more likely to be in `/usr/local/bin` or `$GOPATH/bin`.